# Increase memory of Docker container with docker-compose on Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, out-of-memory, docker-for-windows

On Docker for Windows, I have a simple SQL Server container based on `microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer` that is launched with `docker-compose up` via a simple `docker-compose.yaml` file.

Is there a way to allocate more than 1GB of memory to this container? I can do it when running the image directly or when I build my image with `-m 4GB`, but I can't figure out how to do this when using Docker Compose. This container needs more than 1GB of RAM to run properly and all of my research has revealed nothing helpful thus far.

I've looked into the [resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) configuration option, but that only applies when running under Docker Swarm, which I don't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Looking for options to set resources on non swarm mode containers?**
>
> The options described here are specific to the deploy key and swarm mode. If you want to set resource constraints on non swarm deployments, use [Compose file format version 2 CPU, memory, and other resource options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources). If you have further questions, refer to the discussion on the GitHub issue [docker/compose/4513](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513).

You can use the docker-compose file on version 2 instead of version 3. You can use [`mem_limit` (available on version 2)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) to set the memory limit. So you can use a docker-compose file like this:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  sql-server:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=t3st&Pa55word
    mem_limit: 4GB
```

You can check the memory limit using [`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/).

Answer (score 9):

In docker compose version 2.* you could use the [mem_limit](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) option as below

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  my-svc:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
    mem_limit: 4G
```

In docker compose version 3 it is replaced by the [resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) options which requires docker swarm.

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-svc:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4G
```

There is a compatibility flag that can be used to translate the deploy section to equivalent version 2 parameters when running `docker-compose --compatibility up`. However this is not recommended for production deployments

From [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-mode)

> docker-compose 1.20.0 introduces a new --compatibility flag designed
>   to help developers transition to version 3 more easily. When enabled,
>   docker-compose reads the deploy section of each service’s definition
>   and attempts to translate it into the equivalent version 2 parameter.
>   Currently, the following deploy keys are translated:
>
> - resources
> - limits and memory reservations
> - replicas
> - restart_policy
>
> condition and max_attempts All other keys are ignored and produce a
>   warning if present. You can review the configuration that will be used
>   to deploy by using the --compatibility flag with the config command.
>
> We recommend against using --compatibility mode in production. Because the resulting configuration is only an approximate using non-Swarm mode properties, it may produce unexpected results.

Comment: The compatibility flag didn't end up working for me. It complained about using the wrong versions of the compose file. I used the 2.4 format instead.

Answer (score 2):

Was also out for setting this up via docker-compose. Had a hard time figuring out why sql server worked on a new machine but not any longer on my older one. Finally recalled I had tuned the size down able to allocate in Docker Desktop. Utilizing this you find it through the settings button, Resources/Advanced. Setting Memory to 2GB resolved the issue for me.