# docker-compose ignores memory reservation and memory limit

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running container in non-swarm mode. `docker-compose.yml` is configured this way:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: 'w_server'
    restart: always
    build: .
    mem_reservation: '30G'
    mem_limit: '40G'
    environment:
      NODE_USER: '[...]'
```

However, after successful building and starting the container, stats look like this:

```
docker stats --all --no-stream
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
d4426dd4e34d        w_server            0.00%               573.7MiB / 23.55GiB   2.38%               225MB / 8.47MB      0B / 16MB           18
```

I learned about `deploy.resources.reservations` and `deploy.resources.limits`, but it only works in swarm mode and displays warning when building such configuration (and of course, the settings aren't taken into consideration when the building gets processed).

Is there any other way to assign memory resources?

Docker and docker-compose versions are:

```
docker-compose version 1.28.5, build c4eb3a1f
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
```

Edit:

Found out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416158/increase-memory-of-docker-container-with-docker-compose-on-windows), and answers suggest that `mem_reservation` and `mem_limit` are available in `docker-compose.yml` in version 2.x; version 3.x doesn't support it.

However, changing just the version to `2.4` gave exactly the same results: limit reported by `docker stats` was the same, not read from configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your limits for v3 like that:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: 'w_server'
    restart: always
    build: .
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 40g
    environment:
      NODE_USER: '[...]'
```

But, you need use **--compatibility** flag for it to work like:

```
docker compose --compatibility up
```